# Javascript form validation button: Proceed to the next page after form is valid

Tags: javascript, html

My form validation works perfectly, but after the form is valid it dosen't proceed to the next page
when i click on the submit button
Here is the html for the code:

```
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Create Account</h2>
    </div>
    <form id="form" class="form" action="Iphone.html" method="post">
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Drake" id="username" />
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
            <small>Error message</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="username">Email</label>
            <input type="email" placeholder="applehub@gmail.com" id="email" />
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
            <small>Error message</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="username">Password</label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"/>
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
            <small>Error message</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-control">
            <label for="username">Password check</label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password two" id="password2"/>
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
            <small>Error message</small>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="">

        <a href="#" id="login"><p>Have an account? Login.</p></a>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript, i put the submit button `e.preventDefault();` but i can't turn it of when the form is valid:

````
const username = document.getElementById('username');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const password = document.getElementById('password');
const password2 = document.getElementById('password2');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    checkInputs();


    
});

function checkInputs() {
    // trim to remove the whitespaces
    const usernameValue = username.value.trim();
    const emailValue = email.value.trim();
    const passwordValue = password.value.trim();
    const password2Value = password2.value.trim();
    
    if(usernameValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(username, 'Username cannot be blank');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(username);
    }
    
    if(emailValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(email, 'Email cannot be blank');
    } else if (!isEmail(emailValue)) {
        setErrorFor(email, 'Not a valid email');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(email);
    }
    
    if(passwordValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(password, 'Password cannot be blank');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(password);
    }
    
    if(password2Value === '') {
        setErrorFor(password2, 'Password2 cannot be blank');
    } else if(passwordValue !== password2Value) {
        setErrorFor(password2, 'Passwords does not match');
    } else{
        setSuccessFor(password2);
    }
}

function setErrorFor(input, message) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    const small = formControl.querySelector('small');
    formControl.className = 'form-control error';
    small.innerText = message;
}

function setSuccessFor(input) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    formControl.className = 'form-control success';
}
    
function isEmail(email) {
    return /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email);
}```
````

Comment: when you finish the validation why don't use `form.submit();`

Comment: You are not telling it to move to the next page though?

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually redirect after you have checked that the validation is correct.

To redirect to another page, you can use:
`window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";`

If the application is `SPA` , use `browserhistory.push('/uri');`

Comment: Thanks but it just goes to a new page when I refresh the page and it doesn't go back, please anymore suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by for `e.preventDefault();`. If this function gets called, the inital `action` from the form gets 'disabled'.

I think in this situation the best case is to work with flags.
So the solution could look like this:

```
let is_form_checked = false;

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  if(!is_form_checked) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    checkInputs();
    is_form_checked = true;
    
    //resubmit
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work, if I click on submit button the first time the form validation works but if I click on it the second time it just goes to the next page even without me add anything in the fields, please  if you know a way I can write code for the submit button that will validate the form when it's clicked and proceed to the next page when the form is valid  without it affecting my code for the validation in the fields I'll appreciate it.